# ActiveRecord seems to generate query join in the wrong direciton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I apologize if this is a duplicate issue. I had a lot of trouble trying to express this question in a simple search query.

I have two models set up:

```
class LedgerLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ledger_line
end
```

The tables are sound and exist in the database as I would expect them to.

But when I use this command in the ledger_lines controller...

```
@ledger_lines = LedgerLine.joins(:category).all
```

I get this error...

```
SQLException: no such column: categories.ledger_line_id: 
SELECT "ledger_lines".* FROM "ledger_lines" INNER JOIN "categories" ON
"categories"."ledger_line_id" = "ledger_lines"."id"
```

My intention is to left outer join ledger_lines to categories on ledger_lines.category_id. But the query issued seems to be trying to do the opposite, to try and and join categories to ledger_lines on categories_ledger_id (which doesn't exist).

When I write the sql myself in a db tool and execute it everything is fine, with no errors. Here's the SQL I hand-wrote:

```
select *
FROM ledger_lines AS l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS c
ON l.category_id = c.id
```

I'm fairly new to ActiveRecord/Rails so I wonder if I'm just completely misunderstanding the AR join concept. I am following examples and docs from the Rails Guide it sure looks like this is the right way to do it.

Thoughts? Cries of outrage? Wise answers?

Comment: `belongs_to` should be used on the model containing foreign_key. Just swap them around. Any particular reason for left join here? `includes` might be sufficient (it will trigger second db query to load all the associated records, no N+1 and it might be better performing for large number of records than left join)

Comment: The left join is because category_id is not a required field, so I still want to grab ledger_lines that don't have an associated category.

Comment: I gave includes a try and it does work for this. I just wasn't aware of it. I found the ActiveRecord query documentation a bit overwhelming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing the associations.  Since the ledger_lines tables has a category_id foreign key, the category association should be belongs_to:

```
class LedgerLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ledger_lines
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I suppose the language confused me, since I think of a category as a piece of data that "belongs to" a ledger line, especially in OO terms.